# How do I sync two repos where the remote is gone

Tags: git

I have two new servers where my code is checked out from an old server that no longer exists. So I have two repo's both referring to a nonexisting repo. After that there has been development on both servers. Something like this:

```
  r1 - was built existed on an old server
       /                      \
r1 - cloned to new1      r1 - cloned to new2
      |                        |
     r2                       r4
      |                        |
     r3                       r5
```

How do I fix this so that I can `push` and `pull` on both servers and the result will automatically end up on the other server.

I want the revisions to be lined up so that its basically the same in both servers:

```
r1 - r2 - r3 - r4 -r5
```

I have used the following script to create a copy of my setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -fr main_test_repo tmpA tmpB

# Create a repo with one file
mkdir main_test_repo
git init main_test_repo
echo "First file" > main_test_repo/file1
git -C main_test_repo add file1
git -C main_test_repo commit -m 'First file added'

# Clone and make some changes
for x in tmpA tmpB; do
    git clone main_test_repo $x
    echo "$x file content" > $x/${x}_file
    git -C $x add ${x}_file
    git -C $x commit -m "$x added"
done

# Make the origin go away
rm -fr main_test_repo

# Add remote that points to the "other" server
git -C tmpA remote add -f tmp_b $(pwd)/tmpB
git -C tmpB remote add -f tmp_a $(pwd)/tmpA
```

**Q**: So what git magic is needed here to get those two repos play well with each other?

Comment: Make a new empty repo at GitHub or similar. Make this the origin remote for both your new1 and new2. Mirror-push new1. In new2 do a rebase pull. Push. In new1, pull.

Comment: GitHub (or any such service) is not really an option for me in this case. And isn't `git` and the other distributed revision control systems designed to handle just this type of scenario without a central copy of the repo?

Comment: Ok, if that's a parameter, then just tell new2 to rebase pull from new1 and then tell new1 to pull from new2. But I assure you that a third central bare repo, even if you host it yourself, is a better architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a *bare* repo to use as the shared remote.

You could just make each existing repo the other's remote, but it will get messy. So, if you don't want to use github or any other externally- or centrally-hosted repo, just create a bare clone of one:

```
git clone --bare /my/repo/new1/.git /my/shared-remote.git
```

now add that as a remote for new1:

```
cd /my/repo/new1
git remote add shared /my/shared-remote.git
```

(and set `shared` as the upstream for whatever branches you have, with `git remote set-branches shared <branchname>` or `git branch --set-upstream ...`)

finally add it as a remote of `new2` as well, and decide how to merge their changes.

I'd probably rename the duplicated branch, push it to `shared` and then merge them together, but rebasing is fine if you don't mind rewriting history.

Note that where I've written a local path, it can just as easily be a URI so long as you have SSH, or a git server, or some other way of accessing the remote.